What is the meaning of `...` in a type expression inferred by TypeScript?
I have a function say which works like this:

say() ==> ""
say("hello")() ==> "hello"
say("hello")("how")("are")("you")() ==> "hello how are you"

and is implemented in TypeScript like so:
function say(first?: string) {
  if (first === undefined) {
    return ""
  }
  return (second?: string) => {
    if (second === undefined) {
      return first
    }
    return say(`${first} ${second}`)
  }
}

I left the return type off to see what TypeScript would infer, and it gave me this expression:
function say(first?: string): "" | ((second?: string) => string | ...)

The ... seems to refer to the fact that any attempt to infer a type is circular, since

say returns either the empty string or a function that returns either a string or a function that returns either a string or a function that returns either a string or ...

However the use of ... in the TypeScript rendering of the type does not make clear where the circularity or recursion is, and the type feels inexact. This may be a choice on the part of the TypeScript team. Is there a way to express the type more accurately? Something along the lines of

the function that when given an optional string parameter returns either the empty string or the type t such that t is the type of functions that when given an optional string parameter returns either a string or a t


Looks just like a recursive type type F = (first?: string) => (string | F);. I am not sure, however, if the language would allow you to call it more than once, since one of the possible return types is just string which is not callable.

You seem to be asking more than one question. Can you [edit] the post to include only a single, direct question?

^ Assuming you're just seeking accurate type information for your function signature (specifically the return type), here's an example which demonstrates a recursive overloaded return type (and slightly modified implementation). Does that meet your needs? If so, I can write it as an answer. If not, what did I miss?

The answer here is that while TS has an internal representation of anonymous recursive types, it can't serialize them as a string in an accurate way.  There's a feature request at ms/TS#44045 to allow TS to synthesize type names, but it's not likely to happen. You can synthesize a name yourself, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer; if not, what's missing?

@jcalz Very clear, so the type is indeed internally representable but TS chooses to serialize it with a ... to indicate circularity rather than choosing a bound variable to show exactly where the recursion takes place? The playground link is enormously helpful and certainly worthy of an answer if you would like to write one. The type alias is very clear!

@jsejcksn Good feedback on the question, edited to clarify the main question, which is not TypeScript-specific. Your playground is very helpful! For some reason I forgot that type expressions could themselves be self-referential and was hung up on expressing them with some kind of bound variable. I need to put down the theory books and write more TypeScript!

Ah, I would be happy to write an answer but it seems you've already accepted the other one. The type type Say = (s?: string) => s extends undefined ? string : Say listed there is invalid TypeScript and doesn't work even if you fix it to typeof s. What should we do here?

Do write an answer based on your playground and other commentary and I'll accept it. It should be helpful to others since it is the clearest exposition of recursive types in TypeScript I've seen

While TypeScript can internally represent anonymous recursive types, it cannot cannot currently serialize them accurately. Such types are displayed in IntelliSense with the ellipsis "...", as you've seen, and emitted to declaration files as any.  For example, your say() function would produce the following declaration:
declare function say(first?: string): "" | ((second?: string) => string | any);
//                                                                        ^^^

The only way currently to accurately serialize that type would be to give the recursive part a type alias, so it's no longer anonymous and so you can refer to it by name. You can do this manually by inspection (meaning that you have to effectively be your own type checker); your function type is equivalent to
declare function say(first?: string): SayReturn;
type SayReturn = "" | ((second?: string) => string | SayReturn);

which can be confirmed by annotating the return type of say with SayReturn and making sure nothing breaks:
type SayReturn = "" | ((second?: string) => string | SayReturn);

function say(first?: string): SayReturn { // okay
  if (first === undefined) {
    return "" // okay
  }
  return (second?: string) => {
    if (second === undefined) {
      return first
    }
    return say(`${first} ${second}`) // okay
  }
}

There is a feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#44045 to have TypeScript automatically synthesize a type alias for such types (presumably with a human-unfriendly generated name like __Type001). There's also microsoft/TypeScript#30979 which would generate inline type aliases that are locally scoped. And there was also a suggestion at microsoft/TypeScript#517 to support some sort of syntax like ^ for anonymous recursive types.  But none of those features are currently part of the language. So for now you'll have to either give up on serialization or do it manually.
Playground link to code

Do note that this question is asking for what the ... refers to and how to give it a proper name. It is not asking for a fully generic conditional type that accurately-as-possible represents what say() does for all inputs. If I were doing that I might write this complicated thing. But that's not the question.
